# Can't install/update modules on Drupal 8.9.6 with composer 2.0

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

I'm trying to install a module on a Drupal 8.9.6 using composer 2.0 but I get the next error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cweagans/composer-patches 1.6.7 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - drupal/varbase_heroslider_media 7.13.0 requires cweagans/composer-patches ~1.0 -> satisfiable by cweagans/composer-patches[1.6.7].
    - drupal/varbase_heroslider_media is locked to version 7.13.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.
```

Then, I've tried to update cweagans/composer-patches to 1.7 because this issue was solved [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9470). But I get the next error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/drupal-library-installer-plugin 0.3 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - drupal/varbase_heroslider_media 7.13.0 requires drupal/drupal-library-installer-plugin ^0.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal-library-installer-plugin[0.3].
    - drupal/varbase_heroslider_media is locked to version 7.13.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.
```

Ok, then, I've tried to update drupal/drupal-library-installer-plugin I get again the first error. It is a circle and I can't update Drupal.

How could I do it?

Comment: `You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with`- anything unclear about that message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drupal/drupal-library-installer-plugin` has not seen any updates since more than five years(!). Either search for an alternative, or downgrade Composer to v1